# To create VM of Softlayer by image

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to create VM by image via Python api. However, I get error:

```
"SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue): 
Invalid value provided for 'blockDeviceTemplateGroup.globalIdentifier'.
A valid global identifier is required for a template."
```

my code is as following :

```
import SoftLayer
from SoftLayer import VSManager
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'SLXXXXX'
API_KEY = 'bdf4f3124810a9e685a57xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

mgr = SoftLayer.VSManager(client)
vsi = mgr.create_instance( hourly=True,  image_id=2221859, hostname='p01', domain='esm.com',  cpus=1 , memory=1, datacenter='hkg02')
print vsi
```

If I use Python client, and run following command

```
slcli vs create --billing=hourly --image=2221859 --hostname=p01 --domain=esm.com --cpu=1 --memory=1 --datacenter=hkg02
```

I can create the VM.

But by using python program, I cannot create it.

The detail of the image is :

```
:....................:......................................:
:               name : value                                :
:....................:......................................:
:                 id : 2221859                              :
:  global_identifier : 59570b71-0a3e-4327-a89a-3dfc479ba997 :
:               name : tinyproxy                            :
:             status : Active                               :
: active_transaction : -                                    :
:            account : 792321                               :
:         visibility : Private                              :
:               type : System                               :
:               flex : False                                :
:               note : None                                 :
:            created : 2019-04-18T03:04:59-05:00            :
:         disk_space : 1.50G                                :
:        datacenters : hkg02                                :
:....................:......................................:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you got is because you are using the image Id in your python program request instead of the "globalIdentifier".

Try sending the "globalIdentifier" like the below example:

```
vsi = mgr.create_instance( hourly=True, image_id='59570b71-0a3e-4327-a89a-3dfc479ba997', hostname='p01', domain='esm.com', cpus=1 , memory=1, datacenter='hkg02')
```

Comment: vsi = mgr.create_instance( hourly=True, image_id=59570b71-0a3e-4327-a89a-3dfc479ba997, hostname='p01', domain='esm.com', cpus=1 , memory=1, datacenter='hkg02')
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: pls refer to this page https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/managers/vs.html  .  the image_id should be int

Comment: You have to put the globalIdentifier in quotes, like the example: '59570b71-0a3e-4327-a89a-3dfc479ba997'